# Returning vector from function gives "vector subscript out of range" error

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I'm trying to return vector from `calculate_markerVectors` function and copy it to `pose` but i keep encountering "vector subscript out of range" error.

I could try returning by reference but i'd rather know what i'm doing wrong with this kind of function return.

Returned value consists of 3 `double` type elements.
Here is part of the code:

```
cv::Point2d pt(1,1);
bool new_Point = false;

int prog(){
 vector<vector<cv::Point2f>> markerCorners;
 //.....
 if (new_Point == true) {
     vector <double> pose = calculate_markerVectors(markerCorners, pt);  // HERE ERROR OCCURS
     cout << "MARKER POSE" << pose[0] << "," << pose[1] << endl;
  }
 //.....
}

vector <double> calculate_markerVectors(vector<vector<cv::Point2f>> corners, cv::Point2d clickPt)
{

 //some calulation happens here

cv::Point2f S;
S.x = corners[0][2].x - (vec_AC[0] / 2);                
S.y = corners[0][2].y - (vec_AC[1] / 2);
double theta = acos(dot_prod / (scalarSF*scalarST));

vector <double> pos_img;
pos_img.push_back(S.x);
pos_img.push_back(S.y);
pos_img.push_back(theta);

return pos_img;         
}
```

Comment: is `markerCorners` filled properly?

Comment: You should try using a debugger. Visual Studio has a fantastic debugger.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with how you're returning the vector in the code you've shown. Are there any error cases with returns in the code `//some calculation happens here` ?

Comment: @fdan Yes. It has 1 element which is vector with 4 elements.

Comment: I would add a length check before you access pose elements [0] and [1] and try and identify when a vector is being returned with too few elements.

Comment: As @fdan says. You show where you declare `markerCorners`, but not where you set its contents. Specifically, where you add element at position [0][2] for use in calculate.

Comment: Going step by step with debbuger it didn't even go to executing 'calculate_markerVectors'. That's why i'm confused.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is caused by the parameters given to the fn as opposed to the return value.

Comment: @Rafael if you can't reach the function, how do you know your program crashes theres? there is missing too much code, post an example so we can reproduce the crash

Comment: @fdan Srory, stated it poorly. It didn't execute function properly, just crash at start.

Comment: Thank you all for sugestions. I was accesing markerCorners wrong in calculation part. Error about vector out of range was about size of vector inside 'calculate_markerVectors' all along, not returned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a debugger for cases like this.

I can't find anything logically wrong with your code. But when using vectors you should always check to see if you are accessing an index beyond the size of the vector.

In this case, I would check to see if `corners.size() > 0`, `corners[0].size() >= 2` and `vec_AC.size() >= 1`. Once you do this, you should be guaranteed that `pos_img` will be filled correctly or not at all.

Next, before accessing `pose` I would check to see if `pose.size() >= 1` before accessing `pose[0]` and `pose[1]`.

Doing these checks correctly will completely avoid the vector subscript out of range error and will also help you trace down why `markerCorners` does not have the size you expect it to have.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. It helped to find problem. It was size of vector inside function all along, not returned value.

Comment: Or even better don't use a variable length data structure for data that will always be the same size. That way these problems cannot happen in the first place. OpenCV has all these types ready for you to use.

Comment: @Rafael if you'd like to close this question as answered, just select the grey checkmark next to an answer to accept the answer.